# Async load UIImages stored in a observable object in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage, swift5

**How to async load images that're fully stored in an Observable Class?**

All other questions are about async loading from a remote data source (websites, urls etc). But I want to know how to async load in images from a ObservableObject that contains an array of UIImages.

Right now, because I'm just taking images using the camera and showing them, it would freeze my app whilst all those images load in.

ImagesModel

```
imagesModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var images: [UIImage] = []
  @Published var imageName: String = ""
}
```

imagesView

```
var imgModel: [ImagesModel]

var body: some View {
  ScrollView {
    VStack {

      ForEach(imgModel) { imgEle in
        ForEach(imgEle.images) { img {
          Image(uiImage: img)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }

        Text("\(imgEle.imageName)")
      }
    }

  }
}
```

This is accessed through a NavigationLink and it would freeze for 5ish seconds with just 10-15 photos.

Unfortunately I cannot just slap DispatchQueue.main.async inside the view to load the images.

Is there anyway to async load those UIImages so that my app doesn't completely freeze. Something like being able to access the view, but it's blank and then populates with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load images in background queue, like

```
class ImagesModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var images: [UIImage] = []
  @Published var imageName: String = ""
  
  func load() {
    guard !images.isEmpty else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // ... load here
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           // ... update here
            self.images = loadedImages
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** currently you do not observe `ImageModel`, so it is better to move one model related `ForEach(imgEle.images)` into separated view and make `ImagesModel` observed there.